# Blackberry - Icon path

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I'm trying to change the icon for a blackberry app created by phonegap, but I can't find the folder with the default icon to change it. Can anyone help me? I just need the icon's path to paste my custom icon.

Thank U!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blackberry 10 you can add

```
icon -> www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80

splashscreen -> www/res/screen/blackberry/splash
```

replace with your custom icon and splash.

and clean and rebuild